# With mongoose, I'm trying to find documents with matching 3 different properties, I get empty array in the user If statement executes the else part

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, conditional-statements

In mongoDB with mongoose, I'm trying to find documents with matching 3 different properties, Event though I get empty array in the user If statement executes the else part, If statement here is not working correctly, I get `{ status: 401, message: "Email/Phone/Username already used" }` as response

```
const email = req.body.email;
  const phone = req.body.phone;
  const username = req.body.username;
  //searching if User already exists
  User.find({
    email,
    phone,
    username
  })
    // .then(res => res.json())
    .then(user => {
      console.log(user);
    // logs empty Array here
      if (!user) {
        const newUser = new User({
          firstName: req.body.firstName,
          lastName: req.body.lastName,
          email: req.body.email,
          username: req.body.username,
          password: req.body.password,
          phone: req.body.phone,
          gender: req.body.gender,
          dateOfBirth: req.body.dateOfBirth,
          status: req.body.status
        });

        //encrypting password with bcrypt
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
          bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            newUser.password = hash; //hash is new encrypted password
            newUser
              .save() //saving user
              .then(() =>
                res.json({
                  status: 200,
                  message: "User registered Successfully!"
                })
              )
              .catch(err => console.log(err));
          });
        });
      } else {
        return res
          .status(401)
          .json({ status: 401, message: "Email/Phone/Username already used" });
        //creating new User
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [.find()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-find) method will return an array of documents that match the filter. If there is no match, it will return an empty array. So `!user` will alway be false.

In your case, you may use `!user.length` or `user.length == 0` or use [.findOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOne) method.

Comment: Thanks, I keep getting another problem also, The User.find method only searches for email, does not matches other parameters(username, phone), If there is any user with same phone email and username, I dont want to register them

Comment: If so you need to use `$or` in your query. You can find more info at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Comment: Thank you! for your help